# Convergence in Complex Plane

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing

Suppose that $z_n,z \in G = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{z:z \leq 0 \}$ and $z_n=r_ne^{i\theta_n}, z = re^{i\theta}$ where $- \pi < \theta, \theta_n < \pi$.

Prove that if $z_n \to z$, then $\theta_n \to \theta$ and $r_n \to r$.

Here is what I have tried:

If $z_n \to z$, then $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N >0$ such that for all $n \geq N, \quad |z-z_n|< \epsilon$.

If we rewrite $z$ and $z_n$, we obtain the following expression:

$|re^{i\theta} - r_ne^{i \theta_n}| < \epsilon$. If we assume this, then we may have $|r-r_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|e^{i\theta} - e^{i \theta_n}| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Here is where I am stuck because I am not even sure if separating the inequality above is allowed/justified. However, I am thinking of somehow using this "epsilon over 2" trick along with the triangle inequality. Furthermore, I think I would have to use the fact that $- \pi < \theta, \theta_n < \pi$, which I would assume can be employed after we convert the exponential to cosines and sines using Euler's identity.

Any help on this problem is greatly appreciated. It is a problem from John Conway's *Functions of One Complex Variable, Second Edition*.

Comment: For $r$, use $r_n = |z_n|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to go this way:

- start by getting rid of $r_n$, which is $=|z_n| \to |z|=r$
- then divide your $\epsilon$ inequality so you're left with having to show that $e^{i t_n} \to 1$ implies $t_n \to 0$
- finish by invoking the bijectiveness of $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$ on relevant intervals

Comment: In getting rid of $r_n$, we are using the hypothesis that $z_n \to z$, right? As for the $\epsilon$ inequality, after converting to sines and cosines, this is what I have: $\frac{\cos(\theta) - \cos (\theta_n)}{\epsilon} < 1$ and $\frac{i[\sin(\theta)-\sin(\theta_n)]}{\epsilon}<0$. The reason I have a 0 for the imaginary component is because $1 = 1+0i$. Does this seem reasonable? Thank you for your prompt response.

Comment: On your first point, yes + the continuity of $|\cdot|$ in $\Bbb C$. For the $\epsilon$ thing, I meant divide by $r$ and find an argument to get rid of $r$ and focus on $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for $r_n$: $|r_n - r| = \Big||z_n|-|z|\Big| \le |z_n-z|$

For $\theta_n$, try with proof by contradiction. Assume that $\theta_n$ does not converge to $\theta$ which means there's an $\epsilon$ where you can always find some $n$ so that $|\theta_n-\theta| \gt \epsilon$, draw it on a paper and think what it says about $|z_n-z|$

Comment: In seeking a contradiction, assuming that $|\theta_n - \theta|> \epsilon$, would choosing $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}$ so that we can have $n |\theta_n - \theta| < 1$ suffice since this would not be true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I hope I am not wrong because I am doing it  my head but if $|\theta_n-\theta| \gt \epsilon_0$ then $|z_n-z| \gt r\sin \epsilon_0 $. You should probably explain why $\epsilon_0 $ is small enough. Again try to draw it on a piece of paper to get the intuition. It really helps here